# Techniques to deal with complexity of event driven apps

Tags: events, design-patterns, event-handling

What are the techniques, in general, to write system which receives events from outside world? E.g. Bluetooth application can receive many low level events from HCI. It has to track the state which is very often temporary and allow/disallow operation based on current state.

Are there some specific techniques that helps deal with such complexity? Is there any practical literature to describe some in more details?

Comment: have you checked Observer Design pattern

Comment: @Panther I know observer. I suspect there are more techniques than that.

Comment: Some of us don't find event driven applications to be complex. They're really quite simple once you get used to letting things happen vs. making things happen.

Answer (score 0):

Well observer pattern is the primary and perhaps only pattern to deal with such cases. Though there are variations to it like message driven collaborations, pub-sub, topic or tag based collaborations but most of them all reuse the ideology of observer pattern.

Now comping to complexity. Normally event observers and publishers are stateless in nature. i.e. they receive and event and they either propagate them or consume them. Now propagation is easy  but consumptions may be tricky as the meaning of consumption may differ based on the target and the event type. 
Then there are complexities related to performance of the operations of producing and consuming events. Here again a good design would tend to keep events mutually exclusive to each other. that means that two clicks of a button or two file writes are not dependent on each other in any way. Same should be the case about consumption of event as well. The consumption process should not be dependent on the sequence of arrival of events.

A good event observer design leverages stateless producers and consumers, domain driven event objects (an event object that know where it is supposed to go) and concurrency in producing and consuming to the brim.

Comment: Most of application can not be stateless. There is inherent state for Bluetooth chip e.g. bluetooth is paired or connected. Chip is doing inquiry etc.

Comment: Yes true, but a good design would not make the 'Bluetooth' object as the event producer or consumer. Instead a Bluetooth adapter service or pairing service would generate events and associate the Bluetooth object with the event. The state of the Bluetooth can be accesses form inside the event.